# How to catch event when seekBar reach the end

Tags: android, android-widget

I have media player on screen and one seekBar which shows progress of .mp3 file (position). How to catch event when seekBar reach the end (maximum value ) without using mediaPlayer ?
Is there any other way or I need to check every time progress changed and manually fire event ?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you want to use the MediaPlayer associated with your SeekBar? MediaPlayer exposes an onCompletion callback:

```
OnCompletionListener cListener = new OnCompletionListener(){

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
        //do something
    }
};

mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(cListener);
```

Comment: @Sem_D Reason for that I have one big .mp3 file (that file is whole book, and book has chapters) and I have list of chapters (start_position, end_position) so when it starts new chaper I reset seekBar to zero(seekBar show chapter duration) and I need to load data for that chapter (title, description ... )